# django 1.8.5 migrations fail for AbstractUser model

Tags: python, django, migration

I'm having a weird problem when migrating my project from django 1.7.4 to 1.8.5

In my project I extend the basic User model like so:

App users:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    age = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

Now when migrating in django 1.8.5 for some reasons I have to start by doing

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Which will make the migrations for the users app.

If I do

```
 python manage.py migrate
```

directly after this it fails with this error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "users_user" does not exist
```

Then I do:

```
python manage.py migrate users
```

Which fails

```
"Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes "
RuntimeError: Error creating new content types. Please make sure 
contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually.
```

What is interesting is that even if this fails, now running

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Works

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: messages, staticfiles, django_extensions, allauth, avatar, crispy_forms, debug_toolbar
  Apply all migrations: sessions, users, contenttypes, admin, sites, account, auth, socialaccount
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Creating table avatar_avatar
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying account.0001_initial... OK
  Applying account.0002_email_max_length... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sites.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sites.0002_set_site_domain_and_name... OK
  Applying sites.0003_auto_20151104_1309... OK
  Applying socialaccount.0001_initial... OK
```

Has anyone experienced the same problems when migrating from an older django version to 1.8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually.

All you need to do is add the dependencies so your migrations will run in order.

Have a look at `django.contrib.contenttypes.migrations`, add the latest one as a dependency in `account.migrations` and it should all work fine.

Comment: Thank you that was spot on. However now I get another error that "relation django_site does not exist". But this fixed the problem I was asking about. I will have to look into the other one

Comment: Good luck :) - I think the things to look at are: a missing app (contrib.something?), any app doing some funky code inspection / model loading (like the django debug toolbar) and the dependencies again.